# adding year to dataframe with day-month data only, but knowing starting year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-01', '02-15', '12-31', '01-10', '02-07', '08-20', '12-30', '01-05', '09-07']})
```

i know the starting year is 2020, how to add this year data to the dataframe in a way that it automatically takes into account the year changes. I want to ge:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-01-2020', '02-15-2020', '12-31-2020', '01-10-2021', '02-07-2021', '08-20-2021', '12-30-2021', '01-05-2022', '09-07-2022']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to identify when a "year passes" (the new date is smaller than the prev date), and use these rows to increment the current year, then use [`.stftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to replace the year in each row

```py
initial_year = 2020  
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + f'-{initial_year}', format='%m-%d-%Y')    
df['Year'] = (df['Date'].diff() < pd.Timedelta(0)).cumsum().add(initial_year)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d') + '-' + df['Year'].astype(str)  
df.drop(columns=['Year'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: To understand better, it's always recommended to split the operation into several lines, and print the new column after each line :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Adam.Er8 but with `str.replace`:

```
year = df['Date'].str.replace('-', '').astype(int).diff().lt(0).cumsum().add(2020)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(year.astype(str) + '-' + df['Date'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Date
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-02-15
2 2020-12-31
3 2021-01-10
4 2021-02-07
5 2021-08-20
6 2021-12-30
7 2022-01-05
8 2022-09-07
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't elegant, but it works

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-01', '02-15', '12-31', '01-10', '02-07', '08-20', '12-30', '01-05', '09-07']})
df['Month'] = df.Date.str[:2]
df = df.assign(**{f'sum_{m}': df.Month.eq(m).cumsum() for m in df.Month.unique()})
max_cols=df.iloc[:, 2:].columns
df['Year'] = 2019 + df[max_cols].max(axis=1)
df['Date_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year.astype(str)+'-'+df.Date)

print(df)

    Date Month  sum_01  sum_02  sum_12  sum_08  sum_09  Year  Date_year
0  01-01    01       1       0       0       0       0  2020 2020-01-01
1  02-15    02       1       1       0       0       0  2020 2020-02-15
2  12-31    12       1       1       1       0       0  2020 2020-12-31
3  01-10    01       2       1       1       0       0  2021 2021-01-10
4  02-07    02       2       2       1       0       0  2021 2021-02-07
5  08-20    08       2       2       1       1       0  2021 2021-08-20
6  12-30    12       2       2       2       1       0  2021 2021-12-30
7  01-05    01       3       2       2       1       0  2022 2022-01-05
8  09-07    09       3       2       2       1       1  2022 2022-09-07
```

The idea is to take the max of the number of repeated months and add to the base of 2019 since you know the start year.